# OpenEdge Replication process validation?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

Are there any test scenarios/process to validate OpenEdge Replication in case of disaster?

Any documents/test scenarios that prove the viability of the replication process would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you need to know that your replication is up and running.

**Replication does not replace backup**
(If a user deletes all records or drops tables from the database - that change will be replicated!)

Once a disaster has happened and you need to switch from your source to the target you should do some validation of the database before turning into a valid master. OpenEdge will most likely complain if there are any big errors in the database, transactions not complete etc. But only you can check if your database contains what it should. All crashes tend to loose something - at the very least the not yet committed transactions.

Again: **Replication does not replace backup**

## Validating Replication

You can validate the status of the running replication in different ways:

**Virtual System Tables**

You can access lots of useful data in the VSTs. See the product documentation for further details

_Database-Feature

> The _Database-Feature VST displays the list of features that are active and/or enabled within the
>   database.

_Repl-Server:

> Provides detailed OpenEdge Replication server information

_Repl-AgentControl:

> Provides detailed information about the OpenEdge Replication agents this OpenEdge Replication server is controlling

_Repl-Agent

> Provides detailed OpenEdge Replication agent information

Example code:

```
FIND FIRST _Database-Feature NO-LOCK WHERE _database-Feature._dbFeature_name = "Openedge Replication" no-error.

IF AVAILABLE _Database-Feature THEN DO:
    DISPLAY 
        _Database-Feature._DBFeature_Enabled = "1" LABEL "Repl enabled"
        _Database-Feature._DBFeature_Active  = "1" LABEL "Repl running"
        WITH FRAME frame1 SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN TITLE "Replication".


END.


FIND FIRST _Repl-Server NO-LOCK.
IF AVAILABLE _Repl-Server THEN DO:
    DISPLAY 
        _Repl-Server._ReplSrv-AgentCount       LABEL "# Agents" 
        _Repl-Server._ReplSrv-BlocksSent       LABEL "Blocks sent"
        _Repl-Server._ReplSrv-StartTime        LABEL "Started at"
        _Repl-Server._ReplSrv-LastBlockSentAt  LABEL "Last block sent"
        WITH FRAME frame2 SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN TITLE "Repl Server".
END.

/* To access _Repl-AgentControl you need to connect a soure/master db and not a target/slave db*/
FIND FIRST _Repl-AgentControl NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE _Repl-AgentControl THEN DO:
    DISPLAY 
        _Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-ConnectTime      LABEL "Connected at" 
        _Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-RemoteDBName     LABEL "Remote DB"   FORMAT "x(20)"
        _Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-RemoteHost       LABEL "Remote Host" FORMAT "x(20)"
        _Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-LastBlockSentAt  LABEL "Last block sent"
        _Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-Method           LABEL "Method"
        (_Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-Status = 3049)  LABEL "Normal Status"
        (_Repl-AgentControl._ReplAgtCtl-CommStatus = 1) LABEL "Connected"
        WITH FRAME frame3 SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN TITLE "Repl Agent Control" WIDTH 80.
END.
ELSE DO:
    DISPLAY "Not a source".
END.

/* To access _Repl-Agent you need to connect a target/slave db and not a source ...*/
FIND FIRST _Repl-Agent NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE _Repl-Agent THEN DO:
    DISPLAY
        (_Repl-Agent._ReplAgt-Status = 3049) LABEL "Normal Status"
        (_ReplAgt-CommStatus = 1)            LABEL "Connected"
        WITH FRAME frame4 SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN TITLE "Repl Agent".
END.
ELSE DO:
    DISP "Not a slave db..".
END.
```

**Command Line**

You  can use command line tool **dsrutil** to access information about the replication.

Example:

This will give you a interactive prompt for checking various things:

```
dsrutil db -C monitor
```

You can also use other options (see manuals) for scripting.

Example:

```
dsrutil db -C status detail
```

Writes simply 6021 (and returns OK to the OS) if everything is OK. Check the OE Replication Documentation below for more information.

Sources:

[OE 11.4 Replication Documentation](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/ffr/ffr.pdf)

[OE 11.4 Database Management - Chapter 28](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dmadm/dmadm.pdf)